# Schematic Critique - ATMEGA328P & VS1063

Tags: schematics, atmega328p, mp3

My knowledge in PCB design is very limited, so I've been trying to learn as much as I can on my own. Some feedback on my first design would be incredibly helpful!

### Description

**ATMEGA328P "A"** is supposed to receive serial commands via USB, output RGB LED data through the two LED ports and send commands to ATMEGA328P "B" via I2C.

**ATMEGA328P "B"** is supposed to read MP3 files from an SD card via SPI, and send data to VS1063 to decode which plays audio through AUX jack to external speaker/headphones.

Both ATMEGAs are TQFP. Connected RGB LED strips are 5V.

### Questions

1. Can pins like CS, BSYNC, and DREQ on VS1063 be connected to any GPIO?
2. Do I need the linear voltage regulators for 3V3 and 1V8? Or just voltage dividers?
3. Can ATMEGA328P “B” read MP3 from SD then send data to VS1063 on the same SPI line?
4. Can I leave unused pins floating? Do I connect them to ground?
5. Can I connect I2C lines of ATMEGAs directly?
6. What should I keep in mind when designing the PCB?

Any additional feedback is greatly appreciated!

### Datasheets

[ATMEGA328P Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf)
[VS1063 Datasheet](http://www.vlsi.fi/fileadmin/datasheets/vs1063ds.pdf)
[FT232RL Datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf)

[image: Schematic Image]

Comment: I didnt check everything, but your AVCCs are tied to ground.

Comment: @WesleyLee Thanks for the catch! I tied them to the wrong side of the caps.

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can pins like CS, BSYNC, and DREQ on VS1063 be connected to any GPIO?*

Yes -- this would be the easiest way of using them, and is the approach shown in the example application on page 16 of its datasheet.

*Do I need the linear voltage regulators for 3V3 and 1V8? Or just voltage dividers?*

Regulators.  Current usage can vary over orders of magnitude, so unless you plan on wasting a lot of power heating up your voltage divider a regulator will be necessary.

*Can ATMEGA328P “B” read MP3 from SD then send data to VS1063 on the same SPI line?*

Yes.  You have separate SS lines for each peripheral, so they should work just fine on the same bus.

*Can I leave unused pins floating? Do I connect them to ground?*

On the microcontroller, floating is fine (although I'd suggest attaching them to a pin header in case you find a use for them later).  The VS1063 datasheet states that unused GPIO pins should be grounded through a 100K resister.

*Can I connect I2C lines of ATMEGAs directly?*

I presume you intend to use one as I2C master and the other as an I2C slave to enable communication between the two?  This is supported, although you'll need a pull-up resister on the lines to make it work.  See the [application note here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/atmel-2565-using-the-twi-module-as-i2c-slave_applicationnote_avr311.pdf).

*What should I keep in mind when designing the PCB?*

There doesn't seem to be anything in the design that stands out as needing particular attention; obviously pay attention to getting your decoupling capacitors close enough to the ICs they relate to, and keeping audio paths clear from sources of interference, but it should be reasonably simple design as far as I can see.